# Prototyping in JS: Accessing Parent Methods we not yet derived

Tags: javascript, parent-child, prototypal-inheritance

I am having some problems, trying to inherit from a js prototype.
Problem is that in the Sub Class, if i derive from Master, the initX method from the Master is not known as a method via "this".

```
function master() {};
function sub() {};

master.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        console.log('Master Init!');
        this.initX();                 // This is where the error is thrown
    },
    initX: function () {
        console.log('Master InitX');
    }
};

sub.prototype = new master();
sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
sub.parent = master.prototype;

sub.prototype.init = function () {
    sub.parent.init.call();
    console.log('Sub Init');
}

var subby = new sub();
subby.init();
```

Error Message in Firbug is:

```
TypeError: this.initX is not a function
```

So basically the mother init is called but then it throws an error because of this.initX in the mother init.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually pass the `this` value, so it will be equal to `window` inside `init`. `window.initX` doesn't exist.

`.call()` as it stands is quite useless - use the following instead:

```
sub.parent.init.call(this); // set `this` inside `init`, so that
                            // you'll be calling `initX` on the instance
```

If you want to pass through the arguments as well, a generic way of passing everything along is `.apply` combined with `arguments`:

```
sub.parent.init.apply(this, arguments);
```